# BrowserSync proxy stuck loading

Tags: proxy, gulp, windows-10, wamp, browser-sync

When I run Gulp the UI page works on http://localhost:3001, but on http://localhost:3000 the browser serves a blank page that is stuck loading, no console errors.

I'm using WAMP on Windows 10, Gulp version 3.9.1, BrowserSync version 2.24.4.

This setup was working fine until recently, this has me stumped.

gulpfile.js

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var rename = require("gulp-rename");
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

gulp.task('sass', function(){
  return gulp.src('sass/*.scss')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'expanded'}).on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 versions'))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

gulp.task('compress', function () {
  gulp.src('scripts/js/*.js')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '-min' }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('scripts/minified/'));
});

gulp.task('browserSync', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        proxy: "experiments"
    });
});

gulp.task('watch',['browserSync', 'sass', 'compress'], function(){
    gulp.watch('sass/*.scss', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch('scripts/js/*.js', ['compress']);
    gulp.watch('*.php', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch('*.html', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch('scripts/minified/*.js', browserSync.reload);
})
```

Terminal output

```js
[17:24:44] Using gulpfile ~\Documents\Web Design Local\host\experiments\gulpfile.js
[17:24:44] Starting 'browserSync'...
[17:24:44] Finished 'browserSync' after 9.99 ms
[17:24:44] Starting 'sass'...
[17:24:44] Starting 'compress'...
[17:24:44] Finished 'compress' after 2.2 ms
[Browsersync] 1 file changed (universal.css)
[17:24:45] Finished 'sass' after 174 ms
[17:24:45] Starting 'watch'...
[17:24:45] Finished 'watch' after 17 ms
[Browsersync] Proxying: http://experiments
[Browsersync] Access URLs:
 --------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3000
    External: http://redacted:3000
 --------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://redacted:3001
 --------------------------------------
```

Also looks like the ports are established correctly? Here's before the gulp task is run...

[image: Command prompt output for netstat -ab before running gulp task]

And after...

[image: Command prompt output for netstat -ab after running gulp task]

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this?

Comment: Hi. Nope, it's still not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem was driving me nuts too because recently my proxys stopped working as well.  I was trying to think what I changed - finally I realized I upgraded MalwareBytes to the latest version and it's firewall settings were messing with my ports. I disabled it and now it is working.

I hope this can help someone!

Comment: It was MalwareBytes. You're my hero!

Comment: It looks like its Malwarebytes web protection specifically. An update is on the way, which may fix the problem.

Comment: Latest [Malwarebytes beta](https://forums.malwarebytes.com/topic/227827-malwarebytes-35/?tab=comments#comment-1262373) seems to fix the problem.

Comment: OMFG You've just put and end to a week of misery! It was malwarebytes all along. Thank you so much

Comment: How did you disable MalwareBytes on Mac? Just turning off real-time protection? That didn't help me.

Answer (score 1):

I've set up gulp + browsersync as a test and I think – after some messing about and doc reading – you can change this:

```
gulp.task('browserSync', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        proxy: "experiments"
    });
});
```

to this:

```
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        proxy: 'experiments',
        host: 'experiments',
        open: 'external'
    });
});
```

...and it'll work.

Notes:

- If unset, [`host`](https://browsersync.io/docs/options#option-host) defaults to `null`.
- [`open`](https://browsersync.io/docs/options#option-open) is the browser action to take and defaults to `true`. Other options include `false` to NOT open a browser, and `external` as used here to open the URL specified in `host`.
- I'd also suggest you use an extension, even if it is just for organisation in your Filesystem, vhosts setup and/or WAMP lists etc. [`.dev` is useless over http](https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/) in chrome these days, and `.local` messes with Multicast DNS services. I use `.mere`, you could use `.pix` ;) - your safest most future-proof bet is to use .test as per [RFC 6761](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6761#section-6.2)

Comment: No luck with that either. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

After installing new windows I had the same issue where the browser keep loading without initialising the project.

the issue was Browser Sync package needed an update so I had done the following

```
run the terminal as administrator 
cd into the project folder
rm -rf node_modules (if you already have the package.json file)
npm install
```

also you might need to rebuild the node-sass so you could use the following

```
npm rebuild node-sass
```

then run the gulp project and everything should work fine

Answer (score 0):

when you go to experiments in the browser does it work?

It could be a browser update rather than gulp

I would try changing your host to dev.experiments.co.uk

then change the proxy to dev.experiments.co.uk

Comment: Hi. No luck with that. Thanks for the suggestion though.